# Synchronously sort values in two particular rows of a 2d array according to the first nominated row

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, array-multisort

How do I sort both rows in this array by the `nums` values?

```
[
    'nums' => [34, 12, 13],
    'players' => ['Mike', 'Bob', 'Mary']
]
```

Desired result:

```
[
    'nums' => [12, 13, 34],
    'players' => ['Bob', 'Mary', 'Mike']
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_multisort($x['nums'],$x['players']);`

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`sort function.`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

```
bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
```

This function sorts an array. Elements will be arranged from lowest to highest when this function has completed.

Also check out [`asort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) and [`arsort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)

**EDIT**

I did not take into account your Multidimensional array.

```
   <?php
    //code derived from comments on the php.net/sort page.
    // $sort used as variable function--can be natcasesort, for example
      function sort2d( &$arrIn, $index = null, $sort = 'sort') {
        // pseudo-secure--never allow user input into $sort
        if (strpos($sort, 'sort') === false) {$sort = 'sort';}
        $arrTemp = Array();
        $arrOut = Array();

        foreach ( $arrIn as $key=>$value ) {
          reset($value);
          $arrTemp[$key] = is_null($index) ? current($value) : $value[$index];
        }

        $sort($arrTemp);

        foreach ( $arrTemp as $key=>$value ) {
          $arrOut[$key] = $arrIn[$key];
        }

        $arrIn = $arrOut;
      }
    ?>
```